# javascript putting text together

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function

```
function x{
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Thank you! You have answered correctly to:";
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="";
....
}
```

How i can put together "message"+"score" + questions, So it prints out = You have answered correctly to: 6 questions. Now i have: You have answered correctly to 6.
I tried:

```
document.getElementById("xx").innerHTML="questions";
```

but then score disappears.

Comment: Please include a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including your HTML) to help clarify your issue.

Comment: "Putting text together" is technically called "string concatenation" (for Google). You should also look at "template literal interpolation" (which looks like `\`${variable} some literal ${another variable}\``).

Answer (score 4):

String in javascript can be just combined  by adding a `"+"`. (Have a look at **[string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)**)

```
var textA = "this is a"
var textB = "cool text"

var textC = (textA + " " + textB) // == this is a cool text
```

**To your question:**

If I got your thoughts right this is what you should use:

```
function x() {
  var correct_answers = document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML
  var result = "Thank you! You have answered correctly to:" + correct_answers + "questions";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = result
}
```

I really hope this is what you like to achieve. But please add an working example to clarify your problem. `:)`

**EDIT**: You should also have a look at **function-closure syntax**

Your function should look like this:

```
function myfunction() {
  // your code
}
```

And your html looks a bit wrong:

```
<div id="myDIV"></div>
```

Tags (myDIV) should be closed!

Comment: This would result in a syntax error, you're missing parenthesis in your function definition

Comment: Can i some how put inside here: var textC = (textA + " " + textB) the score? Score is id

Comment: Try to replace `textA` with `id` and you will go `:)` @amilya ||  `var textC = ("your custom text" + id + "looks great!")`

Comment: So if anyone is interested what id did is: document.getEle...=( "You answered correctly :" + a + " question  "); and i defined a=0; in script and incremented it in correct questions :)

Comment: @amilya Yeah, looks like a working solution! **ProTip**: `Don't use short names for variables or functions like "a" or "x". Try to use names you will remember later on because if your code get's bigger you will get REALLY confused.` Believe me `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You should also di it like this:

```
<div id="myDIV"></div>
```

The same should be done for the other div elements